# how does $_session work? and have i done something wrong? php

Tags: php, session

i am new to php and coding in general. i wanted to make a signup/login system. the signup and login function works but when i login i want to stay on index.php and change the context. but for some reason it doesn't work. have i done something wrong?
this is my login code:
(gebruikersnaam = username & wachtwoord = password)

```
    <?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}

include "../../db/dbconnect.php";
include "logs.inc.php";


$gebruikersnaam = mysqli_real_escape_string( $db, $_POST['gebruikersnaam'] );
$wachtwoord = mysqli_real_escape_string( $db, $_POST['wachtwoord'] );
$salt = "46elg9hl50h[[erlt".$wachtwoord."tesy45745jytj57sasfq";

if( empty( $gebruikersnaam ) || empty( $wachtwoord ) ){
    header( "Location: ../index.php?/Fields=Empty" );
    exit();
}

$sql = mysqli_query( $db, "SELECT * FROM organisatie WHERE OrgGebNaam='$gebruikersnaam' OR OrgEmail='$gebruikersnaam'" );
$result = mysqli_num_rows( $sql );

if( $result < 1 || $result > 1){
    header( "Location: ../index.php?/Error/result" );
    exit();
}
else {
    if( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $sql ) ){
        $hashCheck = password_verify( $salt, $row['OrgWW']);
        if( $hashCheck == false ){
            header( "Location: ../index.php?/Error/Password_Incorrect#1");
            exit();
        }
        else if( $hashCheck == true ){
            $_SESSION['ID'] = $row['gebruikerID'];
            $_SESSION['Geb'] = $row['gebruikersnaam'];
            log_ingelogd();
            header( "Location: ../index.ad.php?/Welcome.".$gebruikersnaam );
            exit();
        }
    }
    else{
        header( "Location: ../index.php?Error/Password_Incorrect#2");
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

and this is index.php:

```
    <?php
    include 'header.php';
    include '../db/dbconnect.php';
    error_reporting(0);

    if( !isset( $_SESSION['ID']) && !isset( $_SESSION['Geb'])) {
    ?>
        <section>
            <table id="login-table">
                    <form action="include/login2.inc.php" method="POST">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan=2 style="text-align: center;"> Login Formulier</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><div class="table-text">Gebruikersnaam: </div></td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="login-table-text" name="gebruikersnaam" required title="Vul hier uw gebruikersnaam in." placeholder="Gebruikersnaam"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><div class="table-text">Wachtwoord: </div></td>
                        <td><input type="password" class="login-table-text" name="wachtwoord" required title="Vul hier uw wachtwoord in." placeholder="Wachtwoord"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan=2 style="text-align: center;"><button id="login-btn" name="submit">Inloggen</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
                <form action="signup.php" method="POST">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan=2><hr></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><div class="table-text">Als u geen account heeft: </div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan=2 style="text-align: center;"><button id="signup-btn" name="signup">Maak een account aan ></button></td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
            </table>
        </section>
    <?php
    } // ending if statement.
    $gebruikersnaam = $_SESSION['Geb'];
    $sql = mysqli_query( $db, " SELECT * FROM gebruikers WHERE gebruikersnaam = '$gebruikersnaam'" );
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $sql );
    if( $row['IsAdmin'] == 1){  
    ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <table class="box-information">
                <tr class="box-information-titel">
                    <td>Gebruikers</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p class="box-information-omschrijving">Bekijk hier de gegevens van alle gebruikers, maak gebruikers aan, verwijder gebruikers en bewerk de gegevens van gebruikers.</p>
            <div id="box-btn-gebruiker">
                <a href="gebruikers.php"><button class="box-btn">Bekijk ></button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <table class="box-information">
                <tr class="box-information-titel">
                    <td>Onderhoud</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p class="box-information-omschrijving">Bekijk hier het onderhouds tabel zodat u onderhoud kan uitvoeren.</p>
            <div id="box-btn-onderhoud">
                <a href="onderhoud.php"><button class="box-btn">Bekijk ></button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <table class="box-information">
                <tr class="box-information-titel">
                    <td>Organisatie</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p class="box-information-omschrijving">Bekijk hier alle gegevens die een organisatie heeft.</p>
            <div id="box-btn-organisatie">
                <button class="box-btn">Bekijk ></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <table class="box-information">
                <tr class="box-information-titel">
                    <td>Factuur</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p class="box-information-omschrijving">Bekijk hier alle openstaande facturen, maak facturen en factuurregels.</p>
            <div id="box-btn-factuur">
                <button class="box-btn">Bekijk ></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    }

    include 'footer.php';
?>
```

can someone tell me what i did wrong?
edit: (im not sure but...) i think the problem lies here:

```
$gebruikersnaam = $_SESSION['Geb'];
$sql = mysqli_query( $db, " SELECT * FROM gebruikers WHERE gebruikersnaam = '$gebruikersnaam'" );
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $sql );
if( $row['IsAdmin'] == 1){
```

edit: this is my header.php:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
```

?>

Comment: where's your index.php session_start() ?

Comment: without `session_start()` you won't get session variable values. In index.php file you're missing `session_start()`.

Comment: Also: `if(!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }` - Don't do that, always just start a session.

Comment: still doesn't work :/

Comment: Reduce the code complexity if you want to investigate just a piece of its functionality. Regarding your question read [PHP: $_SESSION - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) for a good explanation of how it works.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Please clarify that, and highlight the crucial parts of your code. Is all of that code neccessary to trigger that error?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe missing  session_start(); in file index.php

Comment: add: session_start(); before   if( !isset( $_SESSION['ID']) && !isset( $_SESSION['Geb'])) {

Comment: please remove if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}, Only using session_start()

Comment: You can debug global variable $_SESSION using session_unset() and more PHP function for session

Comment: @PhiCuong session_unset destorys a session,.. how does that aid with debugging a session?